# setting the output field separator in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I'n trying this statement in my awk script (in a file containing separate code, so not inline), script name: print-table.awk

```
BEGIN {FS = "\t";OFS = "," ; print "about to open the file"}
{print $0}
END {print "about to close stream" }
```

and running it this way from the shell

```
awk -f print-table.awk table
```

Where table is a tab separated file, 
My goal is to declare the field separator (FS) and the output field separator (OFS) within the  external function, and calling from the shell simply the

```
awk -f file input
```

without setting the field separator in the command line with -F"\t"
and without stdout it to a sed statement replacing the tab with a comma,

Any advise how can i do that?

Comment: Are you just trying to replace tabs with commas? `tr \\t , < input`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to convince awk that something has changed to get it to reformat $0 using your OFS. The following works though there may be a more idiomatic way to do it.

```
BEGIN {FS = "\t";OFS = "," ; print "about to open the file"}
{$1=$1}1
END {print "about to close stream" }
```

Comment: You should do like anubhava `{$1=$1}1`.  This `$1=$1` fails if first field is `0`.  It will then be not true and not be printed.

Comment: So it does. I had what anubhava wrote originally but then tried to "golf" it down for terseness. `NF=NF` avoids the zero problem but still has the empty string version so I guess the longer version it is.

Comment: Hi Etan, thx for the reply, but whats the reason for this? why shall i  alter one of the field or 'fake' to alter one of the fields? i thought that the BEGIN routine task was to initiate attributes to be applied to the main routine regardless, i dont understand why a change is necessary....

Comment: Because ask doesn't format $0 according to OFS unless it has to rebuild the contents of $0. Until, and unless, you convince awk it needs to do that it leaves the contents of $0 intact, OFS is used for generated output only. If you read the second to last paragraph of the awk man page's Fields section you will see reference to this concept.

Comment: @EtanReisner What do you mean by "still has empty string version"?

Answer (score 10):

You need to alter one of the field in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t";OFS=","; print "about to open the file"} {$1=$1}1' file
```

Comment: hey Anubhava, what does the 1 after the {$1=$1} means? also, you say "you need to alter one of the field", but as far as i know "i usually use bash" , $1=$1, does not alter $1, it reassigns the same value to it.

Comment: Yes I meant reassignment only. `$1=$1` doesn't change the field value but forces to reformat the input record using provided OFS as comma. Also `1` in the end can be any other non-zero value as well which basically tells awk to print input record.

Comment: @anubhava In which case is the `1` needed? For example, also empty fields are printed without it: `echo ",0,eh" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";OFS="--"} {$1=$1} {print $0}'`

Comment: That `awk` can rewritten as: `awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";OFS="--"} {$1=$1} 1`