# AWK's delimiter in output file

Tags: shell, unix, awk

My Input file is like :

```
1,mad,retl,231,tcs
2,vais,
3,ram,bfs
4,sam,ins
5,tina,bfs
```

I m not sure about number of columns in my output.
O/P file :

```
1|mad|retl|231|tcs
2|vais|
3|ram|bfs
4|sam|ins
5|tina|bfs
```

I tried with code :

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";OFS="|"} {print $0}' INPUT_FILE
```

The result is comma seperated.
Can any assist

Comment: Add `$1=$1` you need to rebuild the line.i.e `awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";OFS="|"} $1=$1{print $0}'` or you could just omit the `print $0` as this is the default action.

Comment: @JID This does not work correctly, it will fail for all line starting with  `0`. `0,ram,bfs` will not printed.  You need `{$1=$1}{print $0}` or as Avinash posted or I in comment to his post. So do not use  `'$1=$1'` always use `'{$1=$1}1'`

Comment: @Jotne true, considering it started at 1 and appears to be incrementing  i didn't think it would be a problem though.

Comment: @JID It will also remove blank lines.  So to be sure always reconstruct all lines `'{$1=$1}1'`.  `'$1=$1'` This will only reconstruct line if they not are blank or not starting with `0`

Comment: @jotne Also didn't look like a problem but yeah okay

Answer (score 1):

Simply you could try the below.

```
$ awk '{gsub(/,/,"|")}1' file
1|mad|retl|231|tcs
2|vais|
3|ram|bfs
4|sam|ins
5|tina|bfs
```

**OR**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="|"}{$1=$1}1' file
1|mad|retl|231|tcs
2|vais|
3|ram|bfs
4|sam|ins
5|tina|bfs
```

Comment: Copycat! Also sed would be more suitable for the first `sed 's/,/|/g'`

Comment: Or like this  `awk -F, '{$1=$1}1' OFS=\| file`

Comment: @JID i didn't see your comment. I just searched the SO about this problem and then finally i found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20844751/3297613). According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844666/setting-the-output-field-separator-in-awk#comment31266297_20844751) comment `$1=$1` will fail.

Comment: Thanks Avinash. Can you tell me what " {$1=$1}1 " do?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844666/setting-the-output-field-separator-in-awk#comment31268786_20844755) comment.

Answer (score 1):

With **sed**:

```
sed 's/,/|/g' File
```

Just substitute `,` with `|` globally.

With **tr**:

```
tr ',' '|' < File
```