# In AWK `rec=rec","$i` doesn't work as expected, where $i is each field in a record

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

I've my `vmstat` output on a linux box as such:

```
# cat vmstat.out
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0      0 2675664 653028 3489156    0    0     1    19   22    7  5  1 94  0  0
```

I intend to keep the value under each field in a comma separated format along with timestamp(of course to use it as CSV file to be later transferred to our very loving MS Excel). So basically this is what I want:

Expected Output:

```
2016,05,19,23,53,58,1,0,0,2675664,653028,3489156,0,0,1,19,22,7,5,1,94,0,0
```

Script:

```
cat vmstat.out | awk 'BEGIN{"date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S'"| getline dt;}{if (NR> 2) {i=1;while (i < NF) {rec=rec","$i; i++;} print dt,rec;}}'
```

Output that I get from my script:

```
2016,05,19,23,53,58 ,1,0,0,2675664,653028,3489156,0,0,1,19,22,7,5,1,94,0
```

Note the extra space : `58 ,1` and the last `0` missing from Expected Output. I know the part in my script that is messing up is: `rec=rec","$i`

How to get around this ?

Comment: 'while (i <= NF)' should fix the missing 0 at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need to reinvent `awk` features

```
$ awk -v OFS=, 'BEGIN{time=strftime("%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S")} 
                 NR>2{$1=$1; print time,$0}' file

2016,05,19,15,12,29,1,0,0,2675664,653028,3489156,0,0,1,19,22,7,5,1,94,0,0
```

Answer (score 2):

The extra space in `58 ,1` is because you're telling awk to print a space (OFS) between dt (which ends in `58`) and rec (which starts with `,1`) with the comma in `print dt,rec`, nothing to do with `rec=rec","$i`.

The missing last field is because you're telling awk to stop looping before the last field. Changing `while (i < NF)` to `while (i <= NF)` would have fixed that but the loop's not necessary at all (see below).

I'm assuming you don't have GNU awk or you'd be using `strftime()` instead of `date`.

Don't have `shell` call `awk` to call `shell` to call `date` and then a `pipe` to `getline` (which you're using unsafely btw, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline):

```
awk 'BEGIN{"date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S'"| getline dt;} {script}'
```

Just have `shell` call `date`:

```
awk -v dt=$(date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S') '{script}'
```

and after getting rid of the UUOC the full script is simply:

```
$ awk -v dt=$(date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S') -v OFS=, 'NR>2{$1=dt OFS $1; print}' vmstat.out
2016,05,19,14,53,05,1,0,0,2675664,653028,3489156,0,0,1,19,22,7,5,1,94,0,0
```

Answer (score 1):

i <= NF will take care of the missing trailing 0.

Instead of looping over the fields, a more awk'ish way of doing the same thing is to set OFS - Output Field Separator to ",".

`awk '
  BEGIN{OFS="," ; "date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S'"| getline dt;}
  {if (NR> 2) {$1=$1 ; print dt,$0;}}
' vmstat.out`

One small glitch with that is that awk doesn't reformat $0 until something is changed.  Setting $1=$1 is enough to force awk to do that ([setting the output field separator in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844666/setting-the-output-field-separator-in-awk))