# find and replace substrings in a file which match strings in another file

Tags: bash, awk, replace, grep, find

I have two txt files: **File1** is a tsv with 9 columns. Following is its first row (`SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313` is the first column and after Repeat is the 9th column):

```
SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313  Censor  repeat  5       264     1169    +       .       Repeat BOVA2 SINE 1 260 9
```

**File2** is a tsv with 9 columns. Following is its first row (after Read is the 9th column):

```
CM011822.1  reefer  discordance 63738705    63738727    .   +   .   Read SRR6691737.359236 11999 12313; Dup 277
```

File1 contains information of read name (`SRR6691737.359236`), read length (`0_14228)` and coordinates (`11999_12313`) while file two contains only read name and coordinate. All read names and coordinates in file1 are present in file2, but file2 may also contain the same read names with different coordinates. Also file2 contains read names which are not present in file1.

I want to write a script which finds read names and coordinates in file2 that match those in file1 and adds the read length from file1 to file2. i.e. changes the last column of file2:

```
Read SRR6691737.359236 11999 12313; Dup 277
```

to:

```
Read SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313; Dup 277
```

any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is not clear. Could you please provide samples of input and sample of expected output along with your efforts and let us know then.

Comment: Please post what you have already tried

Comment: question is convoluted and inconsistent. please provide more sample input with few duplicates and the corresponding output. The files description and fields delimiters inconsistent with TSV file. Please improve explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If unclear how your input files look look like.

You write:

> I have two txt files: **File1** is a tsv with 9 columns. Following is
>   its first row (`SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313` is the first
>   column and after Repeat is the 9th column):
>
> ```
> SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313  Censor  repeat  5       264     1169    +       .       Repeat BOV, ancd A2 SINE 1 260 9
> ```

If I try to check the columns (and put them in a 'Column,Value' pair):
Column,Value
1,SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313
2,Censor
3,repeat
4,5
5,264
6,1169
7,+
8,.
9,Repeat
10,BOVA2
11,SINE
12,1
13,260
14,9

That seems to have 14 columns, you specify 9 columns...

Can you edit your question, and be clear about this?
i.e. specify as csv
`SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313,Censor,repeat,5,.....`

Added info, after feedback :
file1 contains the following fields (tab-, ancd separated):

1. SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313
2. Censor
3. 5
4. 264
5. 1169
6. +
7. .
8. Repeat BOVA2 SINE 1 260 9

You want to convert this (using a script) to a tab-separated file:

1. CM011822.1
2. reefer
3. distance
4. 63738705
5. 63738727
6. +
7. .
8. Read SRR6691737.359236 11999 12313
9. Dup 277

More info is needed to solve this!

field 1: How/Where is the info for 'CM011822.1' coming from?

field 2 and 3: 'reefer'/'distance'. Is this fixed text, should, ancd these fields always contain these texts or are there exceptions?

field 4 and 5: Where are these values (63738705 ; 63738727) coming from?

OK, it's clear that there are more questions to be asked than can give here …

second change...:

create a file, name if 'mani.awk':

```
FILENAME=="file1"{
        split($1,a,"/");
        x=a[1] " " a[4];
        y=x; gsub(/_/," ",y);
        r[y]=$1;
        c=1; for (i in r) { print c++,i,"....",r[i]; }
}
FILENAME=="file2"{
        print "<--", $0, "--> " ;
        for (i in r) {
                if ($9 ~ i) {
                        print "B:" r[i];
                        split(r[i],b,"/");
                        $9="Read " r[i];
                        print "OK";
                        }
                };
        print "<--", $0, "--> " ;
}
```

After this `gawk -f mani.awk file1 file2` should produce the correct result.

If not, than i suggest you to learn AWK , and change the script as needed.

Comment: I put csv format of columns for clarity: file1: SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313 ;  Censor ;  repeat ;  5 ;      264 ;    1169  ;  + ;      .   ;    Repeat BOVA2 SINE 1 260 9
File2:   CM011822.1 ; reefer ; discordance ; 63738705 ;   63738727 ;   . ;  + ;  . ;  Read SRR6691737.359236 11999 12313; Dup 277
I dont have any coding experience but want to change the file2 to this:  CM011822.1 ; reefer ; discordance ; 63738705 ;   63738727 ;   . ;  + ;  . ;  Read SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313; Dup 277 .  I mean, the script finds matches of file name from file1 and modify file2

Comment: @ManiGhanipoorSamami:  Your question is not clear. I added info/questions which should make clear that this question is 'not good'.  There is information missing which makes it impossible to give an answer. SO is no for giving solutions, It's there for helping others in creating their own solutions. 

Comment: I do not want to convert file1 to file2. I want to change the 8th field of file2 from "Read SRR6691737.359236 11999 12313" to "Read SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313". Other fields of file2 remain unchanged. For the first row of the file2 that I showed, I need a script that find "SRR6691737.359236" and "11999_12313" matches in file1 and add "0_14228" from file1 to the 8th column of file2 in this format: "Read SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313".

Comment: Thanks @LUUK, your script generates this output (tens of them generated): "1 SRR6691737.359236 11999 12313 .... SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313", but I want the output to be in this format: "CM011822.1 ; reefer ; discordance ; 63738705 ; 63738727 ; . ; + ; . ; Read SRR6691737.359236/0_14228//11999_12313; Dup 277" (I want it to be tsv, I made it csv here to make separate columns clear). I.e. I only want to change 9th colummn of file2. I am learning awk, but need this result very soon, i would appreciate it if you could help me resolve this.

Comment: `I am learning awk`, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844666/setting-the-output-field-separator-in-awk