# Combine two columns into new and print all columns

Tags: awk

I want to combine columns 1 and 2 and add them as a new column in my data frame. Then I want to print all the old columns and the newly created column. I can combine the columns using the script below, but not sure how to print all columns, not only the combined:

```
awk ' { print $1 $2 "_" $NF } ' input_file
```

in

```
c1 c2 c3
12 1  12
4 4 57
```

out

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
12 1  12 12_1
4 4 57 4_4
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: What's your field separator? Multiple spaces or one tab?

Comment: So, 12 and 1 give 12_1, 4 and 4 give 4_4, but c1 and c2 should give c4???

Answer (score 4):

If you want to print the `_` between field 1 and 2, then the first output would be `c1 c2 c3 c1_c2` instead of `c1 c2 c3 c4`

You can add a column at the end with the value of `$1` and `$2` and then print the whole line:

```
awk ' { $(NF+1) = $1"_"$2 }1' input_file
```

Output

```
c1 c2 c3 c1_c2
12 1 12 12_1
4 4 57 4_4
```

---

Or you can print the whole line followed by field `$1` and `$2`

```
awk '{print $0, $1"_"$2}' input_file
```

Output

```
c1 c2 c3 c1_c2
12 1  12 12_1
4 4 57 4_4
```

Comment: Nice. How do you specify tab separated output

Comment: @user2300940 If you want to align the columns, you can use `awk '{print($0 FS $1"_"$2)}' input_file | column -t` You could also look at this page [setting the output field separator in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844666/setting-the-output-field-separator-in-awk)

Comment: @user2300940 Setting the OFS: `awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}{$1=$1}{print($0 OFS $1"_"$2)}' input_file`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Generic solution in `awk`. Just mention field numbers in `awk` variable named `fields` eg: `1,2,3,4,7,8`(example) and it will add all fields values to last column. Written and tested in GNU `awk` should work in any `awk`.

```
awk -v fields="1,2" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(fields,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
   field[arr[i]]
  }
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(i in field){
      val=(val?val "_":"")$i
    }
  }
  print $0,val
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: How could this be modified to combine fields 1 and 2 and then print all remaining fields 1-7? Something like 1+2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{print $0, (NR>1 ? $1"_"$2 : "c4")}' file
c1 c2 c3 c4
12 1  12 12_1
4 4 57 4_4
```

or to get tab-separated output if your input is tab-separated:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $0, (NR>1 ? $1"_"$2 : "c4")}' file
c1      c2      c3      c4
12      1       12      12_1
4       4       57      4_4
```

or if it isn't:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{$(NF+1)=(NR>1 ? $1"_"$2 : "c4")} 1' file
c1      c2      c3      c4
12      1       12      12_1
4       4       57      4_4
```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk which at `FNR==1` uses the field name in `$NF` to create the field name for the next field (`c3` -> `c4`, `c` -> `c1`, etc):

```
$ awk '{
    printf "%s%s%s\n",
        $0,
        OFS,
        (FNR>1?$1 "_" $2:(match($3,/[0-9]+$/)?substr($3,1,RSTART-1) substr($3,RSTART)+1:$3 1))
}' file
```

Output:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
12 1  12 12_1
4 4 57 4_4
```

Answer (score 1):

golfed version

```
$ awk '$++NF=NR>1?$1"_"$2:"c4"' file

c1 c2 c3 c4
12 1 12 12_1
4 4 57 4_4
```

Comment: here's a more fun way to golf it : `mawk '$++NF=__?$1_$2:__="c4"' _=_` - the strangest way to do `awk` string concat - and it's perfectly safe to have the command line assignment unquoted like that